# In Neo4j what's the best practice to store and match specific path if multiple pathes are exist (with different property)

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am a beginner in Neo4j and graph databases.

I want to store scene details. I have 3 actors. They are fighting in the scene. And I want to store who kicked whom in the specific scene. And not in another scene. I have these relationships:

```
(s1:Scene {id: 1})
(s2:Scene {id: 2})
(a1:Actor) - [:ACTING_IN] -> (s1:Scene {id: 1})
(a1:Actor) - [:ACTING_IN] -> (s2:Scene {id: 2})
(a2:Actor) - [:ACTING_IN] -> (s1:Scene {id: 1})
(a2:Actor) - [:ACTING_IN] -> (s2:Scene {id: 2})
(a3:Actor) - [:ACTING_IN] -> (s1:Scene {id: 1})
(a3:Actor) - [:ACTING_IN] -> (s2:Scene {id: 2})
(a1:Actor) - [:Kick  {scene: 1}] -> (a2:Actor)  
(a1:Actor) - [:Punch {scene: 1}] -> (a2:Actor)  
(a1:Actor) - [:Kick  {scene: 1}] -> (a3:Actor)  
(a1:Actor) - [:Kick  {scene: 2}] -> (a3:Actor)
```

What's the best practice to store these if performance is crucial to query who kicked whom grouped by scenes?
The `scene` in the `Kick` relationship seems to be a Foreign key and I don't know if it is good or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read a lot of articles, I found that the solution is the hyperedges/intermediate nodes.

> One modelling technique that is useful in this model is the concept of a hyperedge. Hyperedges (or intermediate nodes) are often created to model relationships that exist between more than two entities. They are often created to represent the connection of multiple entities at a point in time.

Link to documentation: [Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/modeling-designs/#_example_hyperedges_or_intermediate_nodes)

So an example solution is like this:

```
(s1:Scene {id: 1}) <- [:IN]   -  (ac1:Action {id: 1})
(a1:Actor)          - [:KICK] -> (ac1:Action {id: 1})
(a2:Actor)         <- [:KICK] -  (ac1:Action {id: 1})
```

In a movie, there are a lot of scenes, actions and actors.
An `Action` describes the relationship between two actors in a specific scene.

Answer (score 0):

If not much actions (kick and punch only) then it looks good to me. But if there are hundreds of actions, then you can put the relationship property on the relationship name. For example:

```
:Kick_1 means actor1 kicks actor2 in scene 1 
 or :Kick_2 in scene 2.
```

So that you dont need to add a condition in your where clause to find which scene it is.

Thus, in your query

```
 Match (s:Scene)
 With s
 Match (s) <- [:ACTING_IN] - (a: Actor)
 With s, a
 Match (a) -[r] -> (a2: Actor) where a <> a2
 Return a.name, a2.name, type(r) as action, s.id
```